# Why do objects keep passing through the cylinder?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I've written a code to drop trilobe shaped objects one at a time into a hollow cylinder in Blender, but instead of settling at the bottom, the objects keep passing through to the outside of the cylinder and falling off. How do I prevent this?

Note: I had created the trilobe by adding vertices around the three circular arcs of the trilobe, connecting them with edges, adding a face and then extruding.

Attached is the .blend file as well as some images to better explain my problem.
[image]
[image: Particles falling out of the cylinder]

[image: Trilobe vertices]
[image: Trilobe(after connecting vertices w/ edges, adding face and extruding)]

Comment: Firstly, check that you have Applied Scale to each of the objects and that your Normals are pointing in the right direction. Make sure the container has ‘thickness’ (could add a Solidify modifier) and set the collision shape to ‘Mesh’.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I had already made sure the normals were pointed outwards and set the collision shape to mesh. Can you please explain what you mean by applying scale to the objects? And also why is there a need to add thickness to the container. I did the same analysis for cylinders being dropped and it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: The simulation uses the ‘unscaled’ form of a mesh so if you have scaled a mesh (using ‘S’, for example) it may not behave as expected. Select the object and press Ctrl+A for the Apply menu and select Scale. This will ensure the simulation uses the object at its current size. For the Solidify, yes, your outward pointing normals will make the *outside’ surfaces respond to collisions properly, but from *inside* the normals will still be in the wrong direction if you only have a face as the surface - Solidify will help with that by adding geometry for inside and outside.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I had put the dimension for all objects according to the default scaling (of 1) and had not scaled the objects later. Also, I rerun the simulation after pointing the normals towards the inside following your suggestion, but the issue still persists :( Would you suggest I rerun the simulations again following the steps for Scale anyways?

Comment: If you have changed the dimensions then this will have affected Scale and you will need to Apply Scale before rerunning the simulation. If you select an object and press ‘N’ to show the properties panel and the Scale isn’t 1.0 for each of the X,Y,Z directions then you’ll likely get an unrealistic simulation.

Comment: Hey man, it still doesn't work after all the changes. However, I noticed that changing the Cap Fill Type from Triangle Fan to Ngon prevent particles falling out the bottom of the container. Any help would be very much appreciated :(